# Accessing state of array of children from parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state

What is the method for the parent to access state from an array of children?

Usually you would "lift the state" from a child to the parent, but since you can't use hooks in loops, how would you do this for an array of children?

For example, an array of children with a checkbox in each, and from the parent, trying to find out if the checkboxes are checked or not.

Comment: What is the problem with reading the state of a child?

Comment: @trincot Sorry, I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

> Usually you would "lift the state" from a child to the parent, but since you can't use hooks in loops, how would you do this for an array of children?

It's fine to use hooks in loops **if** the number of loop iterations never changes and the order of the items being looped never changes. (For instance, if you have a component that defines its form fields using a static array, it's fine to use hooks in the body of a loop on that array.)

That said, you'd probably be better off with a single `useState` call with a `Map` of checkbox-to-flag entries. Keep this in the parent, let the parent access it as needed, and pass the flag for the checkbox to the checkbox when rendering it.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const getDefaultCheckboxState = () => new Map([
    ["a", false],
    ["b", true],
    ["c", false],
]);

const Example = () => {
    const [flags, setFlags] = useState(getDefaultCheckboxState);

    const onCheckboxChange = ({currentTarget: {name, checked}}) => {
        setFlags(f => {
            f = new Map(flags);
            f.set(name, checked);
            return f;
        });
    };

    console.log(`Checkboxes: ${[...flags].map(([name, flag]) => `${name}: ${flag}`).join(", ")}`);

    // (This rendering is repetitive and could be done in a loop, but I'm
    // assuming in the real situation they're rendered in various different
    // places.)
    return <div>
        <div>
            <label>
                A:
                <input type="checkbox" name="a" checked={flags.get("A")} onChange={onCheckboxChange} />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                B:
                <input type="checkbox" name="b" checked={flags.get("b")} onChange={onCheckboxChange} />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                C:
                <input type="checkbox" name="c" checked={flags.get("c")} onChange={onCheckboxChange} />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Re my comment on the `return` in that example, here's an example rendering those in a loop instead:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const getDefaultCheckboxState = () => new Map([
    ["a", false],
    ["b", true],
    ["c", false],
]);

const Example = () => {
    const [flags, setFlags] = useState(getDefaultCheckboxState);

    const onCheckboxChange = ({currentTarget: {name, checked}}) => {
        setFlags(f => {
            f = new Map(flags);
            f.set(name, checked);
            return f;
        });
    };

    console.log(`Checkboxes: ${[...flags].map(([name, flag]) => `${name}: ${flag}`).join(", ")}`);

    return <div>
        {[...flags].map(([name, checked]) => <div key={name}>
            <label>
                {name.toUpperCase()}:
                <input type="checkbox" name={name} checked={checked} onChange={onCheckboxChange} />
            </label>
        </div>)}
    </div>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

But re hooks in loops, just for completeness, here's an example using `useState` in a loop:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const checkboxDefinitions = [
    {name: "a", default: false},
    {name: "b", default: true},
    {name: "c", default: false},
];

const Example = () => {
    const checkboxes = checkboxDefinitions.map((def) => {
        const { name } = def;
        const [ checked, setChecked ] = useState(def.default);
        return { name, checked, setChecked };
    });

    console.log(`Checkboxes: ${[...checkboxes].map(({name, checked}) => `${name}: ${checked}`).join(", ")}`);

    return <div>
        {checkboxes.map(({name, checked, setChecked}) => <div key={name}>
            <label>
                {name.toUpperCase()}:
                <input type="checkbox" name={name} checked={checked} onChange={({currentTarget: {checked}}) => setChecked(checked)} />
            </label>
        </div>)}
    </div>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I'm not saying that's a good idea (I'm fairly sure I wouldn't do it here for instance, but I have had reason to do it in other more complex situations).

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Good to know about the loops. Would you recommend disabling the lint rule which causes errors when using a hook in a loop, and is it an acceptable design pattern? Also, with your idea on using a single state in the parent with checkbox values in it, how would you go about updating the state of the correct checkbox for each child?

Comment: @DeanJGrey - It's up to you whether to disable that rule. Granted, it would be an easy thing to get wrong. Re updating the checkbox flags, I was actually in the process of adding an example of that, since it seemed like it could use an example. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much with your help. I'll have a look at inplementing this idea.